# Using opencv to find all contours in an image

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

[image: Image with the program applied]

[image: Image without the program applied]

can someone help me identify the problem in my code, I'm trying to find all the contours in my image and then coat it with an ash border but it seems to only coat some of the contours.
'''

```
image_find_goal = "/absolutePathWays.img"
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
#findGoal(image_find_goal)
img1 = cv.imread(image_find_goal,cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
ret,mask = cv.threshold(img1, 125, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(mask,cv.RETR_TREE,cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for cnt in contours:
    approx = cv.approxPolyDP(cnt,0.01*cv.arcLength(cnt,True),True)
    if len(approx) == 4:
        cv.drawContours(mask,cnt,-1,(119,256,51),5)
mask3 = cv.resize(mask,(640,640))
cv.imshow('IMAGE', mask3)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyWindow(mask3)
```

'''

Comment: Which countours you want to find? All of them or from specific format?

Comment: Are you getting an error message? What about your code does not work as you want?

Comment: @dpetrini I'll like to find the cubic boxes, that's the 3 big red and white/grey boxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I tried printing the values of len(approx), very few values are equal to 4, contours detected might have minor inaccuracies due to which unexpected results might have occured.
- I tried changing the

```
if len(approx) == 4:
```

to

```
if len(approx) >= 4:
```

[Resulting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsIPb.png)

- You can also try removing the condition altogether or edit it as per your requirement.